# Empty Android Module comes with thousands of filed IDs

Tags: android, dex

I am getting `Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536` error. My app has 52142 methods and 67734 fields. Most of the methods comes from Third parties like Android Support Library, Play Services.

My own code only contains 4299 methods while **4299 methods while 41866 fields** ! This is very unusual. When I check further there is a module for example, it has **16 methods and 2305 fields** which is impossible. It seems something fundamentally wrong with my settings or something else.

Hope someone can point the right direction.

Comment: What kind of module?

Comment: Fields get created on a module's `R` class based on its resources. So, if you have a lot of resources (lots of strings, lots of layouts with lots of widgets, etc.), you will have lots of fields.

Comment: I just checked the R class and it is filled with support library resource values. So, if I include support library to multiple modules, all of these fields from support library seems multiplied.